# PHP CLI colours don't show in cygwin

Tags: php, windows, terminal, cygwin, command-line-interface

I use `cygwin` (x86_64-pc-cygwin) + `mintty` (2.3.3) on my windows 8.1 for backend development using PHP (5.6.19)

`composer` (1.0-dev) and `artisan` (5.2.27) (Laravel's console helper) output doesn't show colours while `zsh` prompt, `ls`, `git` and many other commands/programmes show output in colours with no problem.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried different settings trying to fix this, but all failed.

Eventually I found another solution, try using `--ansi` flag with `composer`, `artisan` or `phpspec`